# Importing a jar into an android app

Tags: java, android, jar, importerror

I am trying to import a jar file into an android app that I'm working on, but when I try to declare the import statement in my java code for the app, I get "cannot resolve symbol error".

The jar doesn't have a main method as it is just a class that hashes user passwords and stores the hash in a DB, among a few other things. Here's a screen shot of the situation.

I ran "sync project with gradle files" as well. I'm sure it is something simple. Here's a link to some pics regarding my issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Error in importing, says package doesn't exist:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should add the jar to the compile list too:

```
compile files('libs/Security.jar')
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try in Android Studio `File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` then select `Invalidate and Restart`.